# Using an UML profile in QVTo transformation?

Tags: uml, transformation, m2m, papyrus, qvt

I have defined an UML profile using the Papyrus tool and saved the file as "my_profile.di". How do I use this profile inside a QVTo transformation?

Is it possible to do something like this (I'm not sure how the path to the file should be specified though)?

```
modeltype UMLProfile uses 'platform:/resource/QVT_project_test/my_profile.di';
```

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm completely new to QVT. I hope somebody out there could enlighten me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using UML Profile with QVTo (or any EMF based tranformation language) is a little bit tricky. Short answer, you have to deal with the UML metamodel only, but following the situation, the way to deal with the profile is a little bit different. Basically, there is two scenarios:

1. you want to use a source UML model which uses a Profile/Stereotypes,
2. you want to create a new UML model from another one (or modify an existing one) and apply a Profile/Stereotype on it.

**First Scenario**

You only have to register the UML metamodel and you need to use the operations provided by UML (`getAppliedStereotypes()`,...). Actually, elements on which a stereotype is applied is not recognized as instance of the stereotype. For example, assuming you have a `Property prop` with a stereotype `EAttribute`, QVTo will see `prop` as a `Property` instance with extra-information you can recover instead of a `EAttribute` instance.

Here is a little example considering a kind of `ecore` Profile. I considered an `inout` transformation, which means that the model defined as `inout` will be modified.

```
modeltype UML "strict" uses uml('http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML');

transformation testProfile(inout model : UML);

main() {
  model.objects()[Property]->map copyme();
}

mapping Property::copyme() : Property
when {
  -- You need to use the fully qualified name
  not self.getAppliedStereotype('ecore::EAttribute').oclIsUndefined()
}
{
  -- repr() is used at the end to get a String value from the tagged value
  name := self.name + self.getValue(self.getApplicableStereotype('ecore::EAttribute'), 'attributeName').repr(); -- toString() also works
}
```

And a small request to list all the elements stereotyped by a specific stereotype:

```
model.objects()[Element]->select(e | not e.getAppliedStereotype('ecore::EAttribute').oclIsUndefined());
```

Also, `stereotypedBy(...)` operation seems nice, but it is not yet implemented (on my QVTo version).

**Second Scenario**

This time, you will need to pass the profile as new parameter of your transformation (if your profile is defined in another file). Your profile is a UML model as well, your transformation signature becomes:

```
transformation testProfile(inout model : UML, in profile : UML);
```

First you need to apply your profile to your model:

```
model.objects()[Model].applyProfile(profile.objects()![Profile]);
```

and when you want to apply a Stereotype to an element:

```
-- in context of an element
self.applyStereotype(profile.objects()[Stereotype]![name = 'EAttribute']);
```

If the double filter does not works (I think it will be removed in future QVTo versions), just use a select:

```
self.applyStereotype(profile.objects()[Stereotype]->selectOne(name = 'EAttribute'));
```

Also take a look at the `setValue()` operation ;).

**Final Note**

As you saw, it can be a little bit cumbersome to deal with profile all along your transformation. A smart move could be to derive a metamodel from your profile et code a first transformation that takes your profiled model and translate it as a instance of your derived metamodel. This way, you will be able to deal with metamodel instance instead of "UML instances with extra-information".

**EDIT>**

In order to ease the stereotype handling, you can also define global properties with your most use stereotype:

```
property mystereotype : Stereotype =  profile.objects()[Stereotype]![name = 'EAttribute'];
```